# Call web api from azure function with oauth 2.o c#

Tags: authentication, azure-functions

I am trying to call a web api returning customer data using Azure functions.
How do I store the client credentials and request the access token ? Should I combine the authorization and calling the api under one function or separate it out ?

Any sample code / documentation to help please .

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Client Credentials at Azure KeyVault and link to your Azure function as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) then depends on your flow.

- If you are willing to have Orchestration, you can return the token from an ActivityTrigger function named "GetToken" like below.

```
    [FunctionName("GetToken")]
    public async Task<string> GetToken(
    [ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context)
    {
    }
    
    var token = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("GetToken", null);
```

- If you have a single function, you can have the GetToken code in some helper class and call it

Answer (score 0):

Store the client credentials in Key Vault.

If you are calling the WebAPI once in a while(say once every hour or so), then you can call the oAuth endpoint using the credentials from the Keyvault. But if you are calling the webAPI often, let's say multiple times a minute or more, then you will bombarding the oAuth endpoint that many times for a token. This is not best practice.

There is official Microsoft documentation for this. [Securing oAuth tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/secrets/secure-refresh-tokens).

The documentation says to have a time triggered function fetch the token and encrypt in using a secret from the Keyvault and store it in a DB, cosmos or any storage. The frequency should be less than the token expiry period (if the token expiry is 2 hours, schedule your job for every 1hr 45mins).
Then when you need the token, pick it up, decrypt it and use it for your call.
This should work fine for your use case.